# KeyError when formatting locals

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

I'm facing a `KeyError` I can't explain or understand.
I have a notebook, in which I define a variable `PREFIX` in a cell:

```
PREFIX = "/home/mavax/Documents/info/notebook/log_study"
```

which is simply a path to a folder containing logs, so people using the notebook just need to change the path if they want to execute the code below.

Then, later (quite a bunch of cells beneath), I use it, without any problem:

```
for basename in ["log_converted_full.txt", "log_converted_trimmed.txt"]:
    entries = load_log_for_insertion("%(PREFIX)s/datasets/logs/%(basename)s" % locals())
    pprint(entries)
```

I then get the output I expect, meaning files are found and the (very long) output from the logs is being printed.

I have some more cells describing the structure I implement for this problem, and when the time comes to execute again the same piece of code, I get the `KeyError`:

Code bringing the error:

```
def demo_synthetic_dig_dag(data_size):
    for basename in ["alert_converted_trimmed.txt"]:
        ###
        entries = load_log_for_insertion("%(PREFIX)s/datasets/logs/%(basename)s" % locals())[:data_size]
        g = AugmentedDigDag()
        g.build(entries)

        html(
            """
            <table>
                <tr><td>%s</td></tr>
            </table>
            """ % (
                synthetic_graph_to_html(g, 2, 0.03)
            )
        )
```

and, in the next cell:

```
demo_synthetic_dig_dag(200)
```

Jupyter output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-7c2a79d0afd6> in <module>()
----> 1 demo_synthetic_dig_dag_armen(200)

<ipython-input-178-d17f57de3c01> in demo_synthetic_dig_dag(data_size)
     18     for basename in ["log_converted_trimmed.txt"]:
     19         ###
---> 20         entries = load_log_for_insertion("%(PREFIX)s/datasets/logs/%(basename)s" % locals())[:data_size]
     21         g = AugmentedDigDag()
     22         g.build(entries)

KeyError: 'PREFIX'
```

I'm pretty sure the mistake is quite simple and plain stupid, but still, if someone could open my eyes, i'd be very thankful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside a function, `locals()` is the same as `globals()`, so you have no issue.

When placed inside a function, though, `locals()` doesn't contain `PREFIX` in any way (it is stored in `globals()`, it contains the local names for that function. That's why formatting these fail, it's trying to get a key named `PREFIX` from the dictionary returned from the `locals()` dict.

Instead of formatting with `%`, why not just use `.format`:

```
"{}/datasets/logs/{}s".format(PREFIX, basename)
```

Alternatively, you could bring `PREFIX` in the local scope with an additional parameter to your function:

```
def demo_synthetic_dig_dag(data_size, PREFIX=PREFIX):
```

but I don't see *much* of an upside to that. (Yes, there is a small performance boost for local look-up but I doubt it would play a role)

Comment: worked fine, thanks a lot ! I'm quite new to python, and didn't know the `.format` method .... a good occasion to learn about it today !

Comment: That's great. In general you should read up on the [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method strings provide, it is generally the prefered way to format string in Python 3. (`f`-strings are another newer way but no need to look that up yet)

Comment: OK, i'll follow the advice :)